# ¿Por qué me aparece el error com.android.volley.ServerError pero me crea el usuario?

Tags: java, android, server, volley

Estoy creando una App con Android Studio, de momento tengo creadas dos Activitys, una de login y otra de registro. El .java de login aún la tengo que hacer.

El problema está en que a la hora de hacer un registro, me aparece el error `com.android.volley.ServerError` en la pantalla del móvil (sea un emulador o sea el mío propio) y en el LogCat me aparece este otro:

`com.example.kinder E/Volley: [46] NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected response code 500 for {URL}`

Con esto se puede pensar que el fallo está en el servidor, que no te crea el usuario por motivo X, pero aquí está la cuestión: **Sí que me crea el usuario con todos los datos que yo le envío** (e incluso hace la encriptación de la contraseña).

Les pongo el código del php y el java:

**registro.java:**

```
    EditText Usuario,Apellido,Correo,Contraseña,Contraseña2,Cumpleaños;

    Button Registre;

    //variables de validación
    boolean valCon;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Iniciación de Activiy
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registro);

        //Iniciación de las variables de Activity
        Usuario = findViewById(R.id.et_correo_login);
        Apellido = findViewById(R.id.et_user_apellido);
        Correo = findViewById(R.id.et_mail);
        Contraseña = findViewById(R.id.et_contra);
        Contraseña2 = findViewById(R.id.et_password_repeat);
        Registre = findViewById(R.id.btn_Registro);

        Cumpleaños = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Cumple);

        Cumpleaños.setOnClickListener(this);

        Registre.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public  void onClick(View view){

                if(Contraseña.getText().toString().equals(Contraseña2.getText().toString())){
                    valCon = true;
                }else{
                    valCon = false;
                }
                if(valCon == true){

                    validarUsuario("https://debianlu.com/Kinder/registro.php");
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(Registro.this,"Las Contraseñas no coinciden",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        });

    }
    public void validarUsuario(String URL){

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                if(!response.isEmpty()){ //si el usuari existe

                    Intent intentLoginUsuari = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                    intentLoginUsuari.putExtra("Correo",Correo.getText().toString());
                    intentLoginUsuari.putExtra("Contraseña",Contraseña.getText().toString());
                    startActivity(intentLoginUsuari);
                    finish();

                }else{

                    Toast.makeText(Registro.this,"Error al insertar",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                
                String message = null;
                if (volleyError instanceof NetworkError) {
                    message = "No se puede conectar a Internet... ¡Compruebe su conexión!";
                } else if (volleyError instanceof ServerError) {
                    message = "No se pudo encontrar el servidor. Por favor, inténtalo de nuevo después de un tiempo.";
                } else if (volleyError instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                    message = "No se puede conectar a Internet... ¡Compruebe su conexión!";
                } else if (volleyError instanceof ParseError) {
                    message = "¡Error de sintáxis! Por favor, inténtalo de nuevo después de un tiempo.";
                } else if (volleyError instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                    message = "No se puede conectar a Internet... ¡Compruebe su conexión!";
                } else if (volleyError instanceof TimeoutError) {
                    message = "¡El tiempo de conexión expiro! Por favor revise su conexion a internet.";
                }else if (volleyError instanceof ServerError) {
                    volleyError.printStackTrace();
                }
Toast.makeText(Registro.this,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> parametros = new HashMap<String,String>();
                parametros.put("nom",Usuario.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("ape",Apellido.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("mail",Correo.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("password",Contraseña.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("edat",Cumpleaños.getText().toString());

                return parametros;

            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest); //nos ayuda a procesar las solicitudes hechas de nuestra app.

    }
```

**registro.php:**

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','OF074_WP','U3!cX5!tH5.x','Kinder');

if (!$conn){

        echo("Error conexión");
}

$nom=$_POST['nom'];
$mail=$_POST['mail'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$password= hash('sha512',$password);
$ape=$_POST['ape'];
$edat=$_POST['edat'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO `usuarios` (`Nombre`, `Apellidos`, `Correo`, `Contra`, `Edat`) VALUES ('".$nom."','".$ape."','".$mail."','".$password."','".$edat."')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){

        echo("Usuario Creado");

}else{
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysql_close($conn);

?>
```

Como les digo, problema de la sentencia no es, ya que el usuario me lo genera bien.

¿Qué puede ser?

**EDIT 1**

He modificado las alertas de errores y ahora me aparece el errordel if de "ServerError" (el de `No se pudo encontrar el servidor. Por favor, inténtalo de nuevo después de un tiempo.`).

¿¿Qué sentido tiene que no encuentre el servidor, pero después sí cree el usuario en la base de datos??

**EDIT 2**`

He añadido, cómo me han comentado, la línea `volleyError.printStackTrace(System.out);` para que me diera más detalles, y me ha aparecido todo esto que no entiendo:

```
2022-05-19 00:06:38.373 12515-12515/com.example.kinder W/System.err: com.android.volley.ServerError
2022-05-19 00:06:38.374 12515-12515/com.example.kinder W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException(NetworkUtility.java:201)
2022-05-19 00:06:38.374 12515-12515/com.example.kinder W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:145)
2022-05-19 00:06:38.374 12515-12515/com.example.kinder W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:132)
2022-05-19 00:06:38.374 12515-12515/com.example.kinder W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:111)
2022-05-19 00:06:38.374 12515-12515/com.example.kinder W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:90)
2022-05-19 00:06:38.374 12515-12515/com.example.kinder I/System.out: com.android.volley.ServerError
2022-05-19 00:06:38.374 12515-12515/com.example.kinder I/System.out:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException(NetworkUtility.java:201)
2022-05-19 00:06:38.374 12515-12515/com.example.kinder I/System.out:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:145)
2022-05-19 00:06:38.374 12515-12515/com.example.kinder I/System.out:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:132)
2022-05-19 00:06:38.374 12515-12515/com.example.kinder I/System.out:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:111)
2022-05-19 00:06:38.374 12515-12515/com.example.kinder I/System.out:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:90)
```

Comment: Llevo todo el día buscando información no he encontrado nada de nada. Por favor, ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

He estado pensando en las cosas que he modificado antes de que me fallará el registro, y me he acordado de que he añadido un

`mysql_close($conn);`

para cerrar la conexión sql una vez hecho el insert.

He eliminado la línea y entonces ha vuelto a funcionar.

**EDIT 3**

No entiendo nada ya, he modificado la BD para añadir una tabla que me había olvidado poner (que no tiene nada que ver con la de los usuarios) y ahora cuando registro usuarios no me los crea en la BD, pero tampoco me aparece ni un solo error.

**EDIT 4**

Ya está resuelto, resulta que intentaba guardar una contraseña cifrada en la BD que tenía muy poco espacio para la celda de las contraseñas.

Resulta que me hacía la consulta bien, pero no añadía nada por culpa del espacio de la celda. Al aumentarlo en la BD se ha solucionado.

Comment: Esto no es una respuesta. Si esto es parte de tu pregunta, insertala en la misma, en caso de que sea una respuesta y hayas solucionado algo, indicalo.

Comment: Si ya has resuelto el inconveniente, y esto realmente responde a tu pregunta, [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo agregues un printStackTrace(System.out) en cada uno de los posibles errores, en lugar de solamente actualizar el mensaje.
Para que puedas ver más a detalle, aparte del tipo de error.

Parece ser que se está realizando un commit a la DB antes de completar el llamado.

Comment: Buenas, gracias por tu comentario, he añadido la línea que me has comentado y he modificado la pregunta con el resultado de esta. ¿Qué significa?

Comment: Al hilo de lo que Jose Mario Espinoza comenta, revisa también si no estás creando siempre el mismo usuario en BBDD, puede que te esté dando fallo el insert porque ya lo tienes hecho. ¿O has revisado el log de PHP y te saca "Usuario creado" siempre tras cada llamada?